# Trying to create a HasUnique on EntityTypeConfiguration in Entity Framework (Generics challenge)

Tags: c#, generics, c#-4.0, lambda, entity-framework-4.1

Thanks in advance

I am inheriting EntityTypeConfiguration in order to create a HasUnique method.

My goal is to respect the pattern of the entity framework when it uses Generics. So I do want to accomplish it both using Generics AND Lambda Expressions.

But, I am not an expert with generics neither lambda.

I was studying the EntityTypeConfiguration class and I saw the HasMany method and how it is defined using generics and receives an Expression>>.

So, in the end, what I'd like is something like that:

```
HasUnique(myType => myType.ForeignKey).WithColumn(myTypeAgain => myTypeAgain.VarcharColumn);
```

By now, I ended up doing is:

```
HasUnique("column1").WithColumn("column2").WithColumn("column3");
```

But, as I said, I'd like to accomplish it using generics and lambdas.

I would really appreciate your help.

My best wishes.

Comment: Is your desired syntax fixed? To make it similar to `HasKey`, you'd use `HasUnique(myType => new { myType.column1, myType.column2, myType.column3 })`

Comment: You gave a good suggestion.

But, you know, I really would like to see how would it be the solution for my desired syntax (to do it the same way of EF with HasMany.WithOptional).

Comment: That doesn't use the same syntax because it can't: it needs properties from two different types. But I've tried to answer it as you asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have the code that does the actual work, I'm only including the part that's relevant for expression trees here:

```
public class ExtendedEntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity> : EntityTypeConfiguration<TEntity>
{
    public UniqueConstraintConfiguration<TEntity> HasUnique(string propertyName)
    {
        var result = new UniqueConstraintConfiguration<TEntity>();
        result.WithColumn(propertyName);
        return result;
    }
    public UniqueConstraintConfiguration<TEntity> HasUnique<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> property)
    {
        var result = new UniqueConstraintConfiguration<TEntity>();
        result.WithColumn(property);
        return result;
    }
}
public abstract class UniqueConstraintConfiguration
{
    public UniqueConstraintConfiguration WithColumn(string propertyName)
    {
        // TODO: add code here
        return this;
    }
}
public class UniqueConstraintConfiguration<TEntity> : UniqueConstraintConfiguration
{
    public new UniqueConstraintConfiguration<TEntity> WithColumn(string propertyName)
    {
        base.WithColumn(propertyName);
        return this;
    }
    public UniqueConstraintConfiguration<TEntity> WithColumn<TProperty>(Expression<Func<TEntity, TProperty>> property)
    {
        base.WithColumn(((MemberExpression)property.Body).Member.Name);
        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you very much. I've marked it as the answer.

Now, if it's not asking too much, I'd like to know how could I extract the mapped column of some property.

For example, if my property myType.Property1 is mapped (via Code First) to the fk_property1 database column, how could I get the fk_property1 info?

Thank you guys.

Comment: @MarcoAlves They're not easily available from the `EntityTypeConfiguration`, but if you hold on to the registered unique constraint property names, once you've created an `ObjectContext` (if using `DbContext`, use `IObjectContextAdapter`), you can examine `context.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>().EntitySet.ElementType.NavigationProperties` and then `navigationProperty.GetDependentProperties()`.

Answer (score 1):

My goodness @Marco, why would you put yourself through all of that when your solution is much cleaner/simpler?  Keep the business/schedules/future maintenance/resource pool skill set in mind - and keep it simple!  The oal of Lambdas (any language improvement) was to simplify something complex - not to complicat something simple.